# Optimization of area of rectangle within semicircle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLwSt.png]

The semi-circle is given by $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$

Find the length and width of the rectangle such that it's area is optimized.

How do I deal with problems such as these?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872223/maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-semi-circle-with-radius-r