# Find the dimensions of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a semicircle of radius r.

Tags: calculus, area, maxima-minima

I know that If I were to make a loose coordinate plane graph than the **radius** and (X,Y) of the rectangle would have to mixed into make an equation out of the whole thing. What exactly that equation is beyond me though.

Can someone help me make an equation out of this? I asked my professor and he said that the key to find the local Min-Max.

I'm not given any specific numbers either. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by large rectangle ? Maximum area?

Comment: That's just how the questions is written. I imagine the maximum area? But with no specific numbers i'm lost on how to find them.

Comment: See also: [maximum area of a rectangle inscribed in a semi - circle with radius r.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the equation of semicircle be given by $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (Consider the upper half part)

Now, let the length of side of rectangle be $2a$ and width $b$ vertexes of rectangle will be $$(a,0)~ ;~ (a,b) ~;~ (-a,0) ~; ~(-a,b)$$

[image: Rectangle and Semi-circle]
Area of rectangle : $A=(2a)(b)=2ab ~~\cdots (1)$

Also, $a^2+b^2=r^2$ (The point $(a,b)$ lies on the circle) , Put in (1)

$A=2ab=2a\Big(\sqrt{r^2-a^2}\Big)=2\sqrt{r^2a^2-a^4}=2\sqrt{\dfrac{r^4}{4}-\Bigg(a^2-\dfrac{r^2}{2}\Bigg)^2} \le 2\sqrt{\dfrac{r^4}{4}}$

$$\boxed{A \le {r^2} }$$

Comment: Where does 2a come from exactly? I can see from where you say "rectangle:" that you treat 2a as length and b as your width. I know this is question seems abstract but if you could discuess this more with me than that would be nice.

Comment: @Javier I don't understand what are you asking?Where does it 'come' from, means?

Comment: Why is the lenght of our rectangle 2a? How much is a single a? Is the the coordinate plane dividing the the rectangle a + a?

Comment: It can be taken as $a$ too, than coordinate axis would have divided it into $a/2$, no problem , just for convenience I took $2a$.For your second question, yes by symmetry the center of rectangle should lie on y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $r=1$ without loss of generality.
It is simple to prove that the largest inscribed rectangle has a side on the diameter of the semicircle.
In particular, we may assume that a vertex of the largest inscribed rectangle lies at $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2})$ with $x\in[0,1]$ and its area is given by $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$. On the other hand

$$ \text{argmax}\;2x\sqrt{1-x^2} = \text{argmax}\, x^2(1-x^2) $$
and by the AM-GM inequality $x^2(1-x^2)\leq \frac{1}{4}$, with equality attained only at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. 
It follows that the largest inscribed rectangle is twice a square and its area is $1$ ($r^2$ in the original context).